# Non-internet-dependent instant messaging for Android

Tags: android, lan, instant-messaging

In a LAN without an uplink, is it possible - or rather, feasible - to provide IM for Android users?

You can have a local IM server, but messaging is not much use unless receipients are notified that they have a message - and this seems always to involve GCM, which you need to be online for. It seems the only type of real-time communication you can have on Android that is truly local is SIP, which is only for voice.

It seems there are ways of implementing a local push server but I cannot seem to find any available open-source IM software that actually does or supports this. I am not in a position to spend months developing my own software for this (hence the term "feasible", not just "possible"!), nor do I want to use anything proprietary, even if such a thing does exist.

It looks like TextSecure used to provide this but the the Android version was discontinued.

I'm quite surprised by this dependency, so my question is more of a "really???" than a "how?" - but if there is a how, I would love to hear it!

Comment: It's merely a question of the client and the service you use? You probably need to do some more research. It's not exactly clear why GCM would be required either. In addition ... well it's not really a question according to yourself?

Comment: GCM is needed for push services to be battery friendly. When applications uses GCM for push, the phone only maintains one persistent connection to one server for multiple applications, instead of each application maintaining their own connections (which requires the application to be running in the background, instead of allowing it to be killed by the system, to be woken up by an Intent).

Answer (score 2):

You should try Fire Chat from Open Garden.

It works with Bluetooth or direct Wi-Fi, without any need of any server or internet connection to work.

[Fire Chat on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opengarden.firechat)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, that is a reasonable solution in many cases, however not in mine. Users may wander some distance from each other, but remain connected to the LAN. So it needs to use the LAN, rather than depend on the phone's internal radio.